# Unable to run a Test Suite Setup based on Tags in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a test suite which has 5 tests with combination of different test tags like below

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup           Perform Test Setup

*** Test Cases ***
TC1
    [Tags]  preprod
    log to console  preprod tests : test1

TC2
    [Tags]  Debug
    log to console  debug tests : test2

TC3
    [Tags]  preprod  Debug
    log to console  debug and prerod : test3

*** Keywords ***
Perform Test Setup
    log to console  Test Cases With Tag To Run Are : @{TEST TAGS}
    Run Keyword If  'Debug' in ${TEST TAGS}
    ...  log to console  Debug Test Starting

    Run Keyword If  'preprod' in ${TEST TAGS}
    ...    log to console  preprod tests starting
```

Now when i run the below command with tag

```
robot -i preprod sample.robot
```

Even the keyword from Perform Test Setup of condition hpt is running.

```
=============================================================================
Sample                                                                        
==============================================================================
TC1                                                                   Test Cases With Tag To Run Are : ['preprod']
preprod tests starting
.preprod tests : test1
TC1                                                                   | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TC3                                                                   Test Cases With Tag To Run Are : ['Debug', 'preprod']
Debug Test Starting
preprod tests starting
.debug and prerod : test3
TC3                                                                   | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sample                                                                | PASS |
2 critical tests, 2 passed, 0 failed
2 tests total, 2 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

On giving `'Debug' == ${TEST TAGS}` in Perform Test Setup condition the Keyword does not execute at all.

How to Run the Test Suite Setup or TearDown based on tags with multiple tags and combinations in Tests

Comment: _"Even the keyword from Perform Test Setup of condition hpt is running."_ - what does that mean? What is "hpt"?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You can put any logic you want in `Perform test setup`. What is the rule for what should happen in `Perform test setup`?